# htaccess rewrite rules and get params doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not familiar with URLs rewriting.

So i have this 2 files on a folder called "api":

.htaccess file

> #Fichier .htaccess : /api/
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$  /users.php?user_id=$1 [QSA]
> ```

user.php

```
 $request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    switch($request_method)
    {
        case 'GET':
            // Retrive all users
            if(!empty($_GET["user_id"]))
            {
                echo("_____ID USER FOUND");
            }
            else
            {
                echo("_____ID USER NOT FOUND");
            }
    }
```

And the problem it's in my PHP script i never get my user_id.
Anybody can explain me ?

Comment: Are you sure that your `.htaccess` file is being read? a quick way to test it is adding some garbage to the file, what should trigger an error 500

Comment: No i don't get error even if i put a false php script. 
And when i change my PHP script i get the updates but not with the .htaccess file.
How it's possible ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'i get the updates but not with the .htaccess file'? Whay happens if you add something random to your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: If i change user.php to userpobf.php(some wrong script) in .htaccess file when i use an URL like http://mywebsite.com/api/users the server run the user.php script so the updates in my .htaccess file are not working